# Officer: How to insert picture with it's original width and height

Tags: r, officer

Just like in title: I'd like to add several external images to my `.docx` document. But when using `body_add_img` I need to specify width and height. Is there a way to set them to width and height of original image to be added?

Why I need that? My images (about 50 of them) have all different widths and heights, so it would be painful to manually put their widths and heights in (about 50) `body_add_img` calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your image is a png you can `png::readPNG` to get the width and height in pixels, and divide by your DPI to get the dimensions in inches. (Replace 300 with your DPI)

```
dpi <- 300
img_size <- dim(png::readPNG('image/path/here.png'))/dpi
```

Edit:
If you want the dpi in the doc to be the same as the dpi in the image natively (assuming your png has the dpi stored, I think not all do), use `dpi <- attr(readPNG('image.png', info=T), 'info')$dpi`

Comment: `info<-attr(readPNG('image.png', info=T), 'info')`
`dims<-info$dim/info$dpi`  also works without need of actual DPI knowledge